# the site https://test.domain.co.il is redirected to https://www.domain.co.il

Tags: redirect, url-rewriting, cloudflare

I have a site in prod enviorment that is monitored CloudFlare.

I also have a test site, that is not monitored there.

still, when entering the test site, it redirects to the prod site.

I am a new developer in the company, and I didn't create the redirect action.

The guy that did created it, is unavailable.

I tried looking in Rules, and many more, but nothings seems to be working to fix this.

Is the problem from CloudFlare? I tried checking settings in my server's IIS, but also nothing.

Can you help me determine what is the cause?